# Shovelling a driveway with fire

Tags: internal-consistency

How feasible is it to use a flame-thrower, or some other source of heat, to melt the snow on my driveway instead of a shovel or snow blower to move it? Ignoring the risks of setting my house/lawn/car/dog on fire.

Comment: Yes.  not efficient as ice takes a lot of energy to melt.  Not sure how to answer this in a manner that isn't just a comment.   Is this really a world building question?

Comment: Not very efficient, considering how much time you end up spending at the police station. http://neighborshame.com/fargo-man-arrested-clearing-snow-flamethrower/

Comment: Did you mean to post this on Home Improvement? Not sure how this is a Worldbuilding question.

Comment: I don't see the *worldbuilding* aspect of this.  Perhaps Home Improvement, DIY, or LifeHacks would be better?

Comment: This question should probably be moved to http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Russians would prefer to nuke the snow.

Comment: Dunno about the flamethrower, but a Google search for "electrically heated driveway" comes up with 1.1 million hits.

Comment: @jamesqf trivia: Parts of downtown St. Paul, MN have heated sidewalks to melt snow. They might be steam heated.

Comment: I would really hate to get my girlfriend mad if I had a flamethrower in the house.... Anyway, I agree with Nick2253 that the question should be moved.

Comment: I've seen both heated driveways, as well as flamethrowers used in melting snow from a parking lot.

Answer (score 4):

Feasible enough to be sold for a period of time:

[image]

Comment: "Completely Safe" ... I'm sure small flame guns (erm... throwers?) would never burn anyone. Good find.

Comment: And infeasible enough that the period ended.

Comment: @MikeGossmann I have a hunch they aren't sold anymore more due to liability lawsuits more than lack of feasibility. :) (FYI, they still sell these as 'weeders' in certain areas)

Comment: They still exist.  This would do the job:  http://www.amazon.com/Red-Dragon-VT-3-30-Propane/dp/B00004Z2FQ